# nginx proxy manager: not resolving https but http works

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a little home network with pihole on 192.168.0.3 and a small home server on 192.168.0.41. On the home server, I run a few services, such as dashy, gogs (in docker containers), and I also have a docker container for nginx proxy manager.

I own a domain name (let's call it "domain.name"), which I am using to access my internal services like dashy.domain.name, using nginx proxy manager. In pihole, I have created custom DNS records such as dashy.domain.name.
nginx proxy mgr basically does two things: 1. it uses a SSL certificate with a DNS challenge (from let's encrypt) to secure the traffic to my services, and 2. obviously gets rid of all the different arbitrary ports all these services listen to.

The one thing not working is accessing https://pihole.domain.name. I have configured it in nginx proxy manager to be a proxy host to 192.168.0.3, I am using the same certificate as for everything else, and I have pihole.domain.name configured on my pihole to resolve to 192.168.0.3

I can ping pihole.domain.name - and I can connect to it using http. I cannot however connect to it using https - i get a "connection refused" error.

I found some settings to be put into the advanced configuration of nginx for pihole but from my understanding, they only enable that I don't have to add "/admin" at the end of the path all the time. I found them [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/zxgxxk/run_pihole_and_pfsense_behind_nginx_proxy_manager/) - copied below for convenience.

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://PIHOLE_IP:WEB_PORT/admin/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
proxy_read_timeout 90;
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: I believe "a little home network" is probably off topic :p

Comment: I have seen similar questions here... but happy to put it elsewhere if there's a better place for it?

Comment: I'm not judging, I've seen similar questions closed in seconds :D